# Como o archetype webapp do Maven consegue funcionar sem web.xml?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, tomcat, maven

Experimentei criar uma aplicação *Maven archetype webapp* no Eclipse JEE Photon:

```
File > New > Maven Project > Next > maven-archetype-webapp 1.0
```

Ele gera a seguinte estrutura de arquivos:

```
.
 |-- src
 |   `-- main
 |       `-- java
 |           |-- resources
 |           |-- webapp
 |           |   `-- WEB-INF
 |           |       `-- web.xml
 |           `-- index.jsp
  `-- pom.xml
```

Este é o `web.xml` (ao contrário do que está no título da pergunta ela tem um `web.xml`, só que este não tem nada de interessante dentro - e a pergunta é, como ele localiza `/index.jsp` ao iniciar a aplicação?):

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

O `pom.xml` também não tem nada de especial (segue abaixo, apenas acrescentei a dependência Servlets 3.0.1):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>piovezan</groupId>
    <artifactId>webportfolio2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webportfolio2 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>webportfolio2</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

...e Ta-dá, funciona! Ele acha a página `index.jsp` (que só tem a frase "Hello World")!

[image: Hello World]

Answer (score 1):

Para a diminuição do uso de xml a partir do Servlet 3.0 o uso do web.xml é opcional, como você pode ver no pom do archetype a dependência é acima disto:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Por isto, funciona sem problemas, segue também um artigo com mais [detalhes](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-next-java-web-app-less-xml-no-long-restarts-fewer-hassles-part-1/).